# Error Reporting Registry Location of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, error

I need to stop ArcMap from error reporting during an Arcpy loop. The error report dialog stops my loop and I need for it to go away, permanently

I found [this link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00030000000n000000) which references the registry location as 'HKCU\Software\ESRI\Settings\ErrorReports'.

The actual folder hierarchy in my regedit is much different and I cannot locate the ErrorReports registry 
[image]

What is the actual location of the registry responsible for error reporting in ArcMap 10.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "this link" refers to either http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Error_report_registry_settings/0001000003sr000000/ or http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00030000000n000000?

I cannot say for certain, but sometimes keys for things like this don't exist by default to be modified, and you must create them (as mentioned on one of those help pages). You may need to create a `Settings` key and `ErrorReports` key within it under `ESRI`, then create a `EnableErrorReport` DWORD value set to 0 as described in the help page. Since you're not *changing* a key but rather creating one, this should be fairly safe to test. If it doesn't work, you can just delete the key (and subkeys/values) you created to revert back to the original registry state.

Note that even if Error *Reporting* is disabled, an *error* will still occur with a dialog box (per the help page, unless you add another DWORD to disable that) and a report file written to disk. Therefore your loop may still be broken, and this wouldn't solve your problem.